# Каким образом не учитывать регистр при выборке из базы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть строка с текстом. И есть таблица в базе данных MySQL, в этой таблице записаны некоторые слова.

Мне нужен запрос, который найдет в этой таблице все слова, которые есть в строке с текстом.

Получился такой вот запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slova WHERE INSTR('" . mysql_escape_string($text_article) . "', name)");
```

Но получается что *Слово* и *слово* - это разные слова. Учитывается регистр букв.

Каким образом этого избежать?

Comment: Можно привести оба аргумента к одному регистру, А можно настроить collate

Comment: По умолчанию регистр, как раз, и не учитывается. Какой тип поля `name`? Покажите DDL таблицы

Comment: @AntonShchyrov тип поля VARCHAR

Comment: MySQL поддерживает два типа collation, cs (case sensitive) и ci (case insensitive). В общем случае вам нужно создавать таблицы с правильным collation, здесь проще всего воспользоваться советом выше с приведением к одному регистру.

Comment: [enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3936987/3845306) - говорит, что по дефолту поиск регистронезависимый. А в залинкованном ответе также описан метод приведения к одному регистру.

Comment: @Денис А дальше? Codepage? Collation?

Comment: `LIKE` не подходит?

Comment: помимо привода к одному регистру можно использоват [`COLLATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: @teran можно пример? исходя из моего запроса к бд

Comment: @Денис да вообще странно, в описании `instr()` написано что она и так регистронезависима

Comment: @teran да, странно...

Comment: [пример `collate` относительно `instr`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40239514/1216425)